# AutoMapper does not update nested collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, webapi

I am trying to simplify a process of mapping classes. For this purpose I am using AutoMapper. If no one of classes does not have a nested collection then all is great. But if someone have, I have a trouble with mapping. Collection into a class is overwriting. I found an extension [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection). But it does not work for me.

I am working on a web api project, so some parts of codes here:

```
// Classes for mapping
public class A_Dto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<A_SubItem_Dto> SubItems { get; set; }

}

public class A_SubItem_Dto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public A_Dto A_MainObject { get; set; }
}

public class A_Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<A_SubItem_Resource> SubItems { get; set; }

}

public class A_SubItem_Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// Configure AutoMapper
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddCollectionMappers(), typeof(Startup));
}

// Configure profile class for mapping
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    CreateMap<A_Dto, A_Resource>().ReverseMap()
         .ForMember(m => m.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    CreateMap<A_SubItem_Dto, A_SubItem_Resource>().ReverseMap()
        .EqualityComparison((sir, si) => sir.Id == si.Id);
}

// Controller action with simple test
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(/*...*/)
{
    // Test
    var aDto = new A_Dto()
    {
        Id = 7,
        SubItems = new List<A_SubItem_Dto>() 
        { 
            new A_SubItem_Dto() { Id = 2, Value = "_2_" }, 
            new A_SubItem_Dto() { Id = 9, Value = "_9_" } 
        }
    };

    var aResource = new A_Resource()
    {
        Id = 7,
        SubItems = new List<A_SubItem_Resource>() 
        { 
            new A_SubItem_Resource() { Id = 2, Value = "_222222_" }
        }
    };

    _mapper.Map(aResource, aDto);
}
```

In result `aDto` object contains new collection with one element of `aResource.SubItems`

Could you tell me please, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: AutoMapper will not include destination elements that are not present in source collection and that is default behavior.

Comment: @Prolog, I disagree with you. If you open above link of AutoMapper.Collection you should noticed that "... Will Add/Update/Delete items from a preexisting collection object based on user defined equivalency between the collection's generic item type from the source collection and the destination collection..."

Comment: That's correct. And few lines below you can read also line explaining how mapping will behave when mapping from a collection of dtos to a collection of entities. "If Order exists and OrderDTO doesn't, then AutoMapper will remove Order from collection", that means "If destination collection contains elements not matched with elements from source collection, those elements will be removed." And that is exactly what is happening with your `A_SubItem_Dto` with id `9`. It exists in destination collection, but not in source. It doesn't get matched, so it is removed.

Comment: Notice that your source  resource collection has **less** elements than your destination collection of dtos. So, AutoMapper is mapping that single element that is matching between the two, with id `2`. I'm starting to think that you are passing your variables in wrong order. If dto's are some kind of user input data, then you should map **from dtos** to **entities**. If dto's are just view models for entities, then map **from entities** to **dtos** without existing destination collection.